# Error in alter table reorganize partition for MySQL Cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, clustering, ndbcluster, mysql-cluster

My cluster contains 48 million rows and cluster contains 4 storage nodes . After that I add online storage node and executed `alter table 'customer_tbl' reorganize partition`.
Some parameters of config.ini are :

```
NoOfFragmentLogFiles=100
FragmentLogFileSize=16M
```

When I checked redo information by command all dump 2398; I saw this on my new storage node:

```
REDO part: 0 HEAD: file: 99 mbyte: 11 TAIL: file: 0 mbyte: 0 total: 1600 free: 5 (mb)
REDO part: 1 HEAD: file: 0 mbyte: 0 TAIL: file: 0 mbyte: 0 total: 1600 free: 1600 (mb)
REDO part: 2 HEAD: file: 0 mbyte: 0 TAIL: file: 0 mbyte: 0 total: 1600 free: 1600 (mb)
REDO part: 3 HEAD: file: 0 mbyte: 0 TAIL: file: 0 mbyte: 0 total: 1600 free: 1600 (mb)
```

While my previous existing data nodes have following redo information:

```
REDO part: 0 HEAD: file: 41 mbyte: 3 TAIL: file: 38 mbyte: 10 total: 1600 free: 1559 (mb)
REDO part: 1 HEAD: file: 0 mbyte: 0 TAIL: file: 0 mbyte: 0 total: 1600 free: 1600 (mb)
REDO part: 2 HEAD: file: 0 mbyte: 0 TAIL: file: 0 mbyte: 0 total: 1600 free: 1600 (mb)
REDO part: 3 HEAD: file: 0 mbyte: 0 TAIL: file: 0 mbyte: 0 total: 1600 free: 1600 (mb)
```

Please tell me why free storage is so less in new data node's redo log?
And after some time it gives

> ERROR 1297 (HY000): Got temporary error 410 'REDO log files overloaded (decrease TimeBetweenLocalCheckpoints or increase NoOfFragmentLogFiles)' from NDBCLUSTER

Why doesn't the server use the rest of the three free redo log files which have 1600MB free space?
Please explain what is going on while reorganize partition?